# Преобразовать массив в текстовую строку и обратно

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив созданый вот так:

```
$Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
$array = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query)) {
    $array[] = $row['id'];
    }
//print_r($array);
```

Хотелось бы этот массив из десяти айди преобразовать в текстовую строку (эту строку я хочу занести в базу).

Далее хотелось бы извлечь эту строку в любое удобно время и преобразовать её опять в точно такой же массив.

Буду рад решению в коде, спасибо!

Comment: Воспользуйтесь сериализацией:
[Сериализация объектов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли быВы на моём примере показать? На моём массиве, как его преобразовать в строку, а как потом строку преобразовать в массив. Чисто на моём примере.

Comment: воспользуйтесь в php функциями implode и explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
$array = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query)) {
    $array[] = $row['id'];
}

$arrayAsString = implode(',', $array); // преобразование массива в строку
var_dump($arrayAsString);

$array = explode(',', $arrayAsString); // преобразование строки в массив
var_dump($arrayAsString);
```